# Creating an OMNeT++ project based on the INeT framework?

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am new to OMNet++ and I'm trying to explore the examples and functionalities available in the INeT framework. So how could I create a new project based on this framework?? 
And how do I import certain modules from a different project.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just create a new project, right click on this project --> 'properties' --> 'projec references' and add inet to the references. Now you can use inet files in your project. For example you can use

```
import inet.physicallayer.idealradio.IdealRadioMedium;
```

in your own .ned-File and use IdealRadioMedium as a submodule in your network.

Comment: thanks a lot.. well i tried doing so but I guess something in my settings isn't correct.. all the import statements are faulty though i double checked the paths.
I keep getting undefined module or unregistered class!! even the INeT examples stopped working.

Comment: I reinstalled the INeT framework but still nothing is working in it.. even the basic wireless tutorial example!! is there any command line that could restore the defaults of the OMNeT IDE ???

Comment: can you tell me the exact error message (+ line) when you try to start for example: inet/tutorials/wireless/omnet.ini --> Wireless01?

Comment: I don't know how to attach a photo but it's a pop up message stating:  error during network setup: (omnetpp::cCanvas)WirelessA.Canvas: Error creating figure from NED property @figure[rcvdPkText]: No figure class registered with name 'IndicatorTextFigure' or 'cIndicatorTextFigure'.

Comment: I've double checked the paths of imported files, also the included directories and in the project features and everything is supposed to be working properly.

Answer (score 3):

right click on project and select properties. select project references and mark inet. now you can use inet modules in your project.

[image]